# Group by date in pandas in order to plot categorical distributions

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot data that has been binned by certain date ranges.

Say for example I have the following dataframe:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2013, 6, 1), periods=50, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 3, 50), columns=['x'], index=dates)
df[:3]
            x
2013-06-01  9.819422
2013-06-02  3.659629
2013-06-03  14.862231
```

I would like to group the dates by 3 week intervals and plot the data, this gives me the average I am looking for,

```
df.resample('3w', how='mean')

            x
2013-06-02  11.424715
2013-06-23  9.443888
2013-07-14  8.572851
2013-08-04  9.873879
```

But I would like to keep all of the data so that I can use boxplots in `seaborn` or include standard error using `matplotlib`. I'm completely stuck on how to achieve this without explicitly defining the ranges (which is not possible with the actual dataframes I am working with). It seems there must be a fairly straightforward way to do this in pandas so the output would be something like:

```
            x           week
2013-06-01  9.819422    1
2013-06-02  3.659629    1
2013-06-03  14.862231   1
```

Where `week` is a categorical variable representing the binned data. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use TimeGrouper.

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('3w', how=np.mean)).describe().unstack()
               x                                                                          
           count       mean       std       min       25%        50%        75%        max
2013-06-02     2  10.864835  3.794379  8.181803  9.523319  10.864835  12.206350  13.547866
2013-06-23    21   9.888556  3.452331  3.503944  7.838625   9.739525  12.403285  16.031644
2013-07-14    21  10.475142  2.687320  6.605619  8.399518  11.209683  11.818895  16.265771
2013-08-04     6   9.471931  3.196345  5.492205  8.122607   8.502217  10.901065  14.638198

>>> g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('3w', how=np.mean)).boxplot()
```

[image]

To add the period start date (as a string) to the original data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 3, 50), columns=['x'], index=dates)
tg = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('3W', closed='left'))
df['period'] = None
for p, idx in tg.indices.iteritems():
    df.ix[idx, 'period'] = p.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

>>> df.head()
                    x      period
2013-06-01   7.972202  2013-06-16
2013-06-02  12.184312  2013-06-16
2013-06-03   6.884374  2013-06-16
2013-06-04   8.414091  2013-06-16
2013-06-05  12.368407  2013-06-16
```

Comment: This works well for most situations, however, I was really hoping to be able to generate the dataframe that I provided as an example as there are other statistics I would like to be able to calculate as well.

Comment: try `tg = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('3w'))` and use `tg.` with tab completion to see the available methods.  Note `.get_group` along with all of the other available stats.

Answer (score 1):

Here how I would do:

```
for idx,w in enumerate(df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("3w-SAT"))): # your first day is a saturday
    df.loc[w[0], "week"] = idx+1

# propagate the week number
df["week"] = df.week.fillna(method="ffill") 

# remove added date by the Timegrouper as your number of date is not a multiple of 3 weeks.
df.dropna(inplace=1) 
df.tail()

                    x  week
2013-07-16  15.717111     3
2013-07-17   9.815201     3
2013-07-18   9.426426     3
2013-07-19  12.725350     3
2013-07-20  16.100748     3


# just use seaborn as usual
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="week", y="x") # plot it
```

[image: Timegrouper seaborn]

I don't know if there is a better way to use TimeGrouper with seaborn directly

HTH

Comment: Thanks, this is a good suggestion. I get errors when running this on the full dataset, I think because there are duplicate time indices, but I'm not positive, I need to investigate a bit more.

Comment: @johnchase, try to reduce your dataset , ans share it, so we can reproduce the error. (or make another fake one that reproduces the error)